# Очень долгий ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB

Tags: mariadb, innodb

Решили попробовать перейти с MyISAM на InnoDB.
Попробовал на относительно небольшой табличке с 32 000 000 записями, 1.5Гб данными и 1Гб индекс.

```
MariaDB [mysql]> ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;
запрос очень долго выполнялся, после 10 минут ожидания и 20% первого этапа я его прервал.

MariaDB [mysql]> ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 32173950 rows affected (2 min 3.230 sec) 

MariaDB [mysql]> ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=Aria;
Query OK, 32173950 rows affected (1 min 55.022 sec)    
Records: 32173950  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Настройки 10.3.13-MariaDB

```
key_buffer_size = 1G - временно поставили, раньше было 16G
max_connections = 300
max_user_connections = 280
table_open_cache = 42192
open_files_limit = 165832
max_allowed_packet = 16M
log_warnings = 0
extra_port = 3307
extra_max_connections = 4
sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION


innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 15G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 10
innodb_write_io_threads = 8
innodb_read_io_threads = 8


sort_buffer_size = 12M
read_buffer_size = 2M
join_buffer_size = 4M

thread_cache_size = 256
thread_stack=512K

thread_handling = one-thread-per-connection
thread_pool_max_threads  = 500

read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
net_buffer_length = 1048576
net_read_timeout = 600
net_write_timeout = 600

myisam_sort_buffer_size = 2G
aria_sort_buffer_size = 128M
aria_pagecache_buffer_size = 128M

query_cache_type = OFF

max_heap_table_size = 512M
tmp_table_size = 512M

character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
init-connect="SET NAMES utf8"
default_storage_engine="MyISAM"
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mariadb/mariadb-slow.log
long-query-time = 5
slow_query_log = 1

skip-name-resolve
low_priority_updates = 1
```

И до этого было много проблем с alter table myisam (есть более 20Гб таблицы), у innodb в этом плане все хуже выходит?

Упирается в ssd, в atop показывает busy 100%, чтение/запись максимум по паре сотен iops и несколько MB/s.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  `hash` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `object_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `object_type` enum('city','country',...) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'city',
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `redirect_url_hash` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hash`),
  KEY `object_id` (`object_id`,`object_type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Создание новой таблицы, копирование данных и последующее индексирование наверняка будет быстрее... А вообще-то надо было бы показать структурку таблицы.

Comment: добавил структуру подопытной таблички
на других табличках попробовал, немного быстрее выходит, чем на этой, но все равно раз в 10 медленнее чем myisam или aria

Comment: @Akina alter с изменением типа - это под капотом и есть создание новой таблицы, копирование данных, индексирование, удаление старой таблицы, переименовывание новой

Comment: При создании индексов innodb (а тормозят в первую очередь именно они) необходимо выставлять большое (чем больше тем лучше) значение innodb_sort_buffer_size. Попробуйте, по результатам сообщите плиз

Comment: Попробовал развернуть все у себя на локальном компьютере, aria/myisam пробегают за минуту с небольшим, innodb предположительно будет выполняться больше 30 минут (не дожидаюсь окончания). innodb_sort_buffer_size не помогает. | innodb_sort_buffer_size | 67108864 |

Comment: А, кажется я все понял.... Не обратил до этого внимание, что у вас первичный ключ называется hash ... и видимо им и является... В innoDB таблица _всегда_ храниться в виде кластеризованного индекса по первичному ключу. Это значит, что таблица физически лежит на диске в порядке первичного ключа (ну блоками конечно). Единственный способ записать ее боле менее быстро - подавать на вход записи отсортированные по ключу. Но после вы получите самую медленную таблицу в мире. Первичный ключ в innodb _никогда_ не должен выглядеть как нормально распределенные случайные значения

Comment: А что делать с составными ключами? Например, (object_id, city_id), где object_id до 100кк, а city_id до 300к, чаще всего у одного object один city. Для таких тоже лучше будет сделать AI?

Comment: С составными все отлично. И вышесказанное касается только первичного ключа. Вторичные индексы значения не имеют.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Дропнул PK, добавил UNIQUE на поле hash, стало делать alter на локальном компе за 2-3 минуты (но иногда почему-то час-два), для MyISAM/Aria стабильно полторы минуты. Для InnoDB упирается в SSD, MyISAM/Aria в ядро CPU.

Comment: На локальном все нормально: 2 минуты, но на сервере все равно 2-4 часа идет альтер подобных табличек. Другие таблички аналогично 100 лет пересоздаются. Так что проблема все еще не решена. На сервере почти терабайт хранится, неделями буду альтер делать :)

Comment: Создал тему на англоверсии, там уже конкретно расписал, что проблема все же есть именно с alter любой таблички innodb (если сравнивать с myisam) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55791739/too-long-alter-create-table-innodb